# Links disapear when using text-ident: -9999px

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```css
.card {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
}

.card_colorSecond {
  background-color: #FF1010;
  /* vermelho */
}

.wrap-card-color {
  position: absolute;
  top: -16px;
  left: 0;
}

.card-color {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<li class="card card_colorSecond">
  <nav class="wrap-card-color">
    <ul>
      <li class="card-color card-color_colorFirst"><a href="#">Azul</a></li>
      <li class="card-color card-color_colorSecond"><a href="#">Vermelho</a></li>
      <li class="card-color card-color_colorThird"><a href="#">Verde</a></li>
      <li class="card-color card-color_colorFourth"><a href="#">Amarelo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <p>
    Aliquam voluptate quidem iure excepturi laboriosam ex optio vel et earum eligendi, inventore cum harum, rem tempora, explicabo ipsum quos quis! Nobis ut saepe tempore, veniam excepturi velit rem, cumque cupiditate, quaerat soluta, repellendus ex non?
    Ut pariatur, sit nesciunt!
  </p>
</li>
```

The box works but I can’t click on it.

Please see the image below to understand what I’m trying to do.
[This is how it is now, but i cant click to change the colors, since the links are not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9EyU.png)

Comment: CSS is one of those things where the prime question must be why: Why are you using `text-indent: -9999px`?

Comment: What effect are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have applied `text-indent` on `<li>` elements...it means all the text element inside `<li>` i.e. `<a>` will be indented to the left `-9999px`

Apply text-indent on `<a>` instead of `<li>`..it will intend the text inside `<a>`.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.card {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
}

.card_colorSecond {
  background-color: #FF1010;
  /* vermelho */
}

.wrap-card-color {
  position: absolute;
  top: -16px;
  left: 0;
}

.card-color {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.card-color a {
  text-indent: -9999px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<li class="card card_colorSecond">
  <nav class="wrap-card-color">
    <ul>
      <li class="card-color card-color_colorFirst"><a href="#">Azul</a></li>
      <li class="card-color card-color_colorSecond"><a href="#">Vermelho</a></li>
      <li class="card-color card-color_colorThird"><a href="#">Verde</a></li>
      <li class="card-color card-color_colorFourth"><a href="#">Amarelo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <p>
    Aliquam voluptate quidem iure excepturi laboriosam ex optio vel et earum eligendi, inventore cum harum, rem tempora, explicabo ipsum quos quis! Nobis ut saepe tempore, veniam excepturi velit rem, cumque cupiditate, quaerat soluta, repellendus ex non?
    Ut pariatur, sit nesciunt!
  </p>
</li>
```

Or another option is just set `opacity:0` of the `<a>`...No need to use `text-indent`

```css
.card {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
}

.card_colorSecond {
  background-color: #FF1010;
  /* vermelho */
}

.wrap-card-color {
  position: absolute;
  top: -16px;
  left: 0;
}

.card-color {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.card-color a {
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<li class="card card_colorSecond">
  <nav class="wrap-card-color">
    <ul>
      <li class="card-color card-color_colorFirst"><a href="#">Azul</a></li>
      <li class="card-color card-color_colorSecond"><a href="#">Vermelho</a></li>
      <li class="card-color card-color_colorThird"><a href="#">Verde</a></li>
      <li class="card-color card-color_colorFourth"><a href="#">Amarelo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <p>
    Aliquam voluptate quidem iure excepturi laboriosam ex optio vel et earum eligendi, inventore cum harum, rem tempora, explicabo ipsum quos quis! Nobis ut saepe tempore, veniam excepturi velit rem, cumque cupiditate, quaerat soluta, repellendus ex non?
    Ut pariatur, sit nesciunt!
  </p>
</li>
```